# Trigger Update On Same Objeect

Tags: apex, trigger

I want To update the field with another field of same object..i am wrote the code but it is not populating.

```
trigger ChangeLogChild on Change_Log__c (after Insert) {


    List<Change_Log__c> Change= [select id,CPs_ZIP_Code__c from Change_Log__c 
                                  WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];

    for(Change_Log__c c: Change){

        c.CP_ZIP_Code__c= c.CPs_ZIP_Code__c;  
    }

    update Change;

}
```

`Cp_Zip_Code__c` ,`CPs_zip_Code` fields Api Name different but field labels are same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the functionality you want to achieve you don't really need the record id so you can write the trigger on the before insert event. Try this code.

```
trigger ChangeLogChild on Change_Log__c (before insert, before update) {

 System.debug('ChangeLogChild trigger entered');

    for(Change_Log__c c: Trigger.new){

       System.debug('The current Change Log record is: ' + c);
       System.debug('The current CPS Zip code is: ' + c.CPs_ZIP_Code__c);

        c.CP_ZIP_Code__c= c.CPs_ZIP_Code__c;  
    }

}
```

Comment: Still not working. CP_ZIP_Code__c field value is updated  through trigger from another object . i am Created Cps_Zip_code__c field manually

Comment: Note is a before insert trigger, so it will only work when you create a new object of type Change Log

Comment: ya but after Update Operation also its not populating

Comment: if you need the update event to function, you'd need to add it to the trigger. I edited the code.

Comment: still not working

Comment: do you add any value in the CPs_Zip_Code__c ? Are the 2 fields of the same type? Is the Cp_Zip _Code__c writable?

Comment: ya after adding i am clicking save button

Comment: ya its working Thank uMarc Zahareschu

Comment: @srihari I added a few debug statements in case your code didn't work so you could go in the debug log and check for those statements. If the code is working please select my answer as the right one so that others that might encounter the same issue to be able to see it.

Comment: one more question how to call trigger in existing records suppose i have 50 records now i am wrote the trigger with After insert...but old records are not coming in this trigger...why

Comment: In order to do this you can either download a report with the id of your Change Log it will trigger the records and using data loader mass bulk update them so that it will trigger the update event on each of them OR faster but riskier: go to the developer console and open execute asynchronous apex window and execute the following code: List<Change_log__c> changelogs = new List<Change_log__c>([Select id from Change_log__c]);  update changelogs;

Comment: no that is not my questio....i have object DealSheet___c in that objects already 100 records are there now...i am wrote the trigger for getting all metername__c field and imabalnce for the meter depends on perticular day..now that is working properly for now wt i am creating but existing records it is not working how

Answer (score 0):

You need to add them in query. You missed to add `Cp_Zip_Code__c`  in query.

```
trigger ChangeLogChild on Change_Log__c (after Insert) {


    List<Change_Log__c> Change= [select id,CPs_ZIP_Code__c, Cp_Zip_Code__c from Change_Log__c 
                                  WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
 // Add them in query or use trigger.new
    for(Change_Log__c c: Change){

        c.CP_ZIP_Code__c= c.CPs_ZIP_Code__c;  
    }

    update Change;

}
```

or if this is not formula field then you can use Before insert.

Comment: hi Tushar still not working...in the for loop again i need to take that Trigger.new

Comment: @srihari check now.